# Should object that creates ads (e.g. Banner, Interstitial) be a singleton?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, ads

Following on through the Google AdMob read on implementation for the varying ads:

https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/banner
https://developers.google.com/admob/unity/interstitial

Right now I have a C# Script which implements these ads and I go on to create a game object inside my inspector which has this script.

I believe that this is enough information for me to get a straight forward answer hopefully without any code required and a very general one.

I would like to know whether this object should be initialized only once, ideally in the Main Menu scene and be recycled through the other scenes to manage the reference to these ads.

OR

Delete the existing game object which manages those ads to then have the following scene instantiate a new one, potentially showing a different advert to the one previous.

EDIT:

AdManager Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public class AdManager : MonoBehaviour
{

public static AdManager instance;

//Test id: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
private string APP_ID = "An id";

private BannerView bannerAD;
private InterstitialAd interstitialAD;


private void Awake()
{
    if (instance != null)
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
    else
    {
        instance = this;
        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    }
}



// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    //FOR PUBLISHING ONLY
    //MobileAds.Initialize(APP_ID);

    RequestBannerAD();
    RequestInterstitialAD();
}

private void RequestBannerAD()
{
    string banner_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
    bannerAD = new BannerView(banner_ID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);


    // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
    bannerAD.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
    // Called when an ad request failed to load.
    bannerAD.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
    // Called when an ad is clicked.
    bannerAD.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
    // Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
    bannerAD.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
    // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
    bannerAD.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;

    //FOR PRODUCTION
    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();


    //FOR TESTING
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

    bannerAD.LoadAd(adRequest);

     void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        Display_Banner();

    }

     void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {
        RequestBannerAD();
    }

     void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");

    }

     void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");

    }

     void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
    }
}

public void Display_Banner()
{
    bannerAD.Show();
}


public void DestroyBanner()
{
    bannerAD.Destroy();
}

private void RequestInterstitialAD()
{
    string interstitial_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
    interstitialAD = new InterstitialAd(interstitial_ID);


    // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
    interstitialAD.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
    // Called when an ad request failed to load.
    interstitialAD.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
    // Called when an ad is clicked.
    interstitialAD.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
    // Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
    interstitialAD.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
    // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
    interstitialAD.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;


    //FOR PRODUCTION
    //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();


    //FOR TESTING
    AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

    interstitialAD.LoadAd(adRequest);


    void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {

    }

    void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
    {

    }

    void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");

    }

    void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");

    }

    void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
    }
}


public void Display_Interstitial()
{
    if (interstitialAD.IsLoaded())
    {
        interstitialAD.Show();
    }
}


public void DestroyInterstitial()
{
    interstitialAD.Destroy();
}
```

}

MenuLoader Script (fragment to interstitial call attached to a UI Button):

```
public void LoadGameOver()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndLoad_GameOver());
}

private IEnumerator WaitAndLoad_GameOver()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(gameOver_loadDelay);
    FindObjectOfType<AdManager>().Display_Interstitial();
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
}
```

EDIT 2 (In response to Eliasar):

```
06-20 22:07:13.988  6492  6518 E Unity   : NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
06-20 22:07:13.988  6492  6518 E Unity   :   at AdManager.Display_Banner () [0x00000] in <0b5b8f6032c04370a5fa0fecd73ecd6b>:0 
06-20 22:07:13.988  6492  6518 E Unity   :   at MenuLoader+<WaitAndLoad_Game>d__6.MoveNext () [0x00084] in <0b5b8f6032c04370a5fa0fecd73ecd6b>:0 
06-20 22:07:13.988  6492  6518 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.SetupCoroutine.InvokeMoveNext (System.Collections.IEnumerator enumerator, System.IntPtr returnValueAddress) [0x00027] in <1f017b19aaf9475abf1041405dbaf390>:0 
06-20 22:07:13.988  6492  6518 E Unity   :
```

AdManager:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System;
using UnityEngine;
using GoogleMobileAds.Api;

public static class AdManager
{

    //public static AdManager instance;

    //Test id: ca-app-pub-3940256099942544~3347511713
    private static string APP_ID = "An id";

    private static BannerView bannerAD;
    private static InterstitialAd interstitialAD;


    //private void Awake()
    //{
    //    if (instance != null)
    //    {
    //        Destroy(gameObject);
    //    }
    //    else
    //    {
    //        instance = this;
    //        DontDestroyOnLoad(gameObject);
    //    }
    //}



    // Start is called before the first frame update
    //void Start()
    //{
    //    //FOR PUBLISHING ONLY
    //    //MobileAds.Initialize(APP_ID);

    //    RequestBannerAD();
    //    RequestInterstitialAD();
    //}

    private static void RequestBannerAD()
    {
        string banner_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111";
        bannerAD = new BannerView(banner_ID, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);


        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        bannerAD.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        bannerAD.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        // Called when an ad is clicked.
        bannerAD.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
        // Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
        bannerAD.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
        // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
        bannerAD.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;

        //FOR PRODUCTION
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();


        //FOR TESTING
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

        bannerAD.LoadAd(adRequest);

         void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            Display_Banner();

        }

         void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
        {
            RequestBannerAD();
        }

         void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");

        }

         void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");

        }

         void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
        }
    }

    public static void Display_Banner()
    {
        bannerAD.Show();
    }


    public static void DestroyBanner()
    {
        bannerAD.Destroy();
    }

    private static void RequestInterstitialAD()
    {
        string interstitial_ID = "ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/1033173712";
        interstitialAD = new InterstitialAd(interstitial_ID);


        // Called when an ad request has successfully loaded.
        interstitialAD.OnAdLoaded += HandleOnAdLoaded;
        // Called when an ad request failed to load.
        interstitialAD.OnAdFailedToLoad += HandleOnAdFailedToLoad;
        // Called when an ad is clicked.
        interstitialAD.OnAdOpening += HandleOnAdOpened;
        // Called when the user returned from the app after an ad click.
        interstitialAD.OnAdClosed += HandleOnAdClosed;
        // Called when the ad click caused the user to leave the application.
        interstitialAD.OnAdLeavingApplication += HandleOnAdLeavingApplication;


        //FOR PRODUCTION
        //AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().Build();


        //FOR TESTING
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().AddTestDevice("2077ef9a63d2b398840261c8221a0c9b").Build();

        interstitialAD.LoadAd(adRequest);


        void HandleOnAdLoaded(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {

        }

        void HandleOnAdFailedToLoad(object sender, AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args)
        {

        }

        void HandleOnAdOpened(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdOpened event received");

        }

        void HandleOnAdClosed(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdClosed event received");

        }

        void HandleOnAdLeavingApplication(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            MonoBehaviour.print("HandleAdLeavingApplication event received");
        }
    }


    public static void Display_Interstitial()
    {
        if (interstitialAD.IsLoaded())
        {
            interstitialAD.Show();
        }
    }


    public static void DestroyInterstitial()
    {
        interstitialAD.Destroy();
    }


}
```

MenuLoader (fragment edit):

```
public void LoadGameOver()
{
    StartCoroutine(WaitAndLoad_GameOver());
}

private IEnumerator WaitAndLoad_GameOver()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(gameOver_loadDelay);
    AdManager.Display_Interstitial();
    //FindObjectOfType<AdManager>().Display_Interstitial();
    SceneManager.LoadScene("Game Over");
    AdManager.Display_Banner();
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating a static class file that does not have to inherit from `MonoBehaviour`?

Comment: @Eliasar If I do that then doesn't that mean I have to load the adverts at the same time I am calling them from my class responsible for changing Scene?

Comment: That file and method will be your service hook. If you need to generate a new ad, you don't need to reconnect to your service, you call this static method that returns the ad to your gameobject

Comment: @Eliasar Above shows what I have currently, so in terms of what you said I basically need to make the AdManager class static and directly call the `RequestBannerAD()`  and   `RequestInterstitialAD();` upon scene change, followed by the code to then show the ads? Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I believe so. Remove the `FindObjectOfType<AdManager>` bit and just reference the methods you need from `AdManager` directly. `AdManager` doesn't need to be aware of `Start` in which it's being called.

Comment: @Eliasar See (Edit 2). It meant I had to make the advert objects themselves static though. Am I missing something?